# Dynamically passing URL to custom SoundCloud player

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm trying to use the custom player from SoundCloud with the advanced use of passing the URLs directly to the player. I want one player at the top of the page and then links on a page that play a certain track. I've taken the code from the Red skin example for the toggle player link and tried to add to it to get this to work with no success, the toggle player works, not the play buttons. I'm sure it's something trivial I'm missing. Can anyone suggest where I've gone wrong please? My test code so far can be seen at http://www.grecho.co.uk/samplesuperstore/test.htm

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

live is deprecated in the latest JQuery. Use `.on(` instead

Inseat of

```
$(function() {
  $('a.sc-remote-play1').live('click', function(event) {
    $('a.sc-player').scPlayer({
      links: [{url: "http://soundcloud.com/jacquesmirage/jacques-le-mac-air-race", title:   "Air Race"}],
    });
  });
});
```

remove 'a' (you re pointing a anchor element instead of the player)

```
$(function() {
  $('a.sc-remote-play1').live('click', function(event) {
    $('.sc-player').scPlayer({
      links: [{url: "http://soundcloud.com/jacquesmirage/jacques-le-mac-air-race", title:   "Air Race"}],
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh You're using a. selector, in your event handler you should be pointing to the player directly: $('.sc-player').